# Swift ternary operator compilation error

Tags: swift

Why does this generate an error and how should it be written?

```
    let x = 5
    let y = 4
    var z:Int
    x < 4 ? z = 6 : z = 8
```

The error is "Could not find an overload for < that accepts the supplied arguments"

Comment: @LeoDabus's answer is right, but just to be clear, the reason why your option didn't work is because of the precedence of the various operators. The ternary operator doesn't have to resolve to an expression: it can be just statements too. `x < 4 ? (z = 6) : (z = 8)` Will work, for example.

Comment: @oisdk: please turn your comment into an answer because that deserves my upvote. Never realized the ternary op can be used that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *reason* your ternary operator isn't working there is because of the precedence of the various infix operators. [You can see the operator precedence list here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383) If you look, you'll see that the operators down the bottom are the ones that are usually placed between larger chunks of code. The higher the precedence, the tighter it'll clamp to the expressions to its left (or right). So, you usually want your `=` operator to have a very low associativity, so in an expression like:

```
let x = 2 + 3
```

The `+` will grab the two operands on either side of it *before* the `=` will, so it resolves to:

```
let x = (2 + 3)
```

rather than something like:

```
(let x = 2) + 3
```

Which makes less sense.

The ternary conditional operator has precedence of 100, whereas the `=` operator has precedence of 90. So in your example, when you've got this:

```
x < 4 ? z = 6 : z = 8
```

The associativity goes like this:

```
x...
x < ...
x < 4 // precedence 130, so resolves
(x < 4)...
(x < 4) ?...
(x < 4) ? z...
(x < 4) ? z = ... // Does not yet resolve. Why? Well, here, the ternary isn't 
                  // really an infix. It is special kind of operator that 
                  // takes something between ? and :. So normal associativity
                  // doesn't apply. (I'm still experimenting...)
(x < 4) ? z = 6 : ...
(x < 4) ? z = 6 : z // HERE it resolves. The z is grabbed, as the ternary has 
                    // precedence 100, larger than the 90 precedence of the =
((x < 4) ? z = 6 : z) = 8
```

So because the precedence of the ternary operator is higher than that of the assignment operator, it "grabs" the `z`, and then, when it finds the `=`, it gets all confused. What the compiler sees looks something like this:

```
if (x < 4) { z = 6 } else { z } = 8... // Compiler has a hissy fit
```

So how do you fix it?

```
x < 4 ? (z = 6) : (z = 8) // x < 4 ? z = 6 : (z = 8) works as well
```

The parentheses make the associativity explicit. Why does it work this way in the first place? Well, usually you use the ternary operator to resolve it to an expression (as was in @LeoDabus' answer). And in that case, its associativity means that you *don't* need the parentheses:

```
let z = x < 4 ? 6 : 8
let z...
let z = ...
let z = x ...
let z = x < 4 // < has precedence 130, bigger than =
let z = (x < 4) ? // ? has precedence of 100, bigger than =
let z = if (x < 4) { 6 } else { 8 }
```

I hope that helps, and makes sense. (I might have gotten some of my precedence explanations wrong, I find it quite confusing)

Turns out, I did get some of my precedence explanations wrong. If my explanation had been correct, this wouldn't have worked:

```
x < 4 ? z = 6 : (z = 8)
```

But it does! It turns out, the precedence issues happen *after* the operator, not before. (I explain a bit more above)

Also, the actual if statement with curly braces itself *doesn't* resolve to an expression. So this doesn't work:

```
let z = if (x < 4) { 6 } else { 8 }
```

Comment: All of this is certainly true, but to the basic question of "how should it be written?", I think @LeoDabus has the better answer. That is the way most people will write it, and expect to see it.

Answer (score 2):

```
let x = 5
let y = 4
let z = x < 4 ? 6 : 8
```